# Объявление класса с помощью конструктора

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

Как можно (на основе количества входных данных) объявить класс с параметрами, с параметрами + значением по умолчанию, без параметров? Ведь если же класс объявить в if, то он не будет виден вне if. Допустим такой пример:

```
...
class Time {
...
public:
    Time();
    Time(int h, int m, int s = 0);
    ...
};

...
std::cin >> count_parameters;
int h, m, s;
std::cin >> h >> m >> s;
//_____________________________________________
// if (count_parameters == 0) Time dayTime();
// if (count_parameters == 2) Time dayTime(h, m);
// if (count_parameters == 3) Time dayTime(h, m, s);
//_____________________________________________
dayTime.something();
```

Comment: C++ является языком со статической типизацией и объявлять классы на основе количества входных данных в нем невозможно. ¿Может в этом вопросе идет речь об инициализации экземпляра класса с вызовом разных конструкторов в зависимости от входных данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс копируемый/перемещаемый?

```
Time dayTime;

if (count_parameters == 2) dayTime = Time(h, m);
else if (count_parameters == 3) dayTime = Time(h, m, s);

dayTime.something();
```

Но есть и еще одно решение — настроить значения `h`, `m` и `s` в зависимости от `count_parameters` так, чтобы они соответствовали тому, что нужно получить в каждом случае, и просто создать нужный объект.

Что-то типа

```
if (count_parameters == 2) s = 0;
Time dayTime(h,m,s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Time *dayTime = NULL;

if (count_parameters == 0) dayTime = new Time();
else if (count_parameters == 2) dayTime = new Time(h, m);
else if (count_parameters == 3) dayTime = new Time(h, m, s);
if (dayTime)
    dayTime->something();

delete dayTime;
```

Comment: А потом `dayTime->something();` бросает исключение, и память утекает. :(

Answer (score 0):

Если можно C++17, то решение без `new\delete` (соответственно без динамического выделения памяти) на основе [copy elision](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) и [`std::optional`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional):

```cpp
#include <optional>

...

std::optional<Time> daytime;

if (count_parameters == 0) 
    dayTime.emplace();
else if (count_parameters == 2) 
    dayTime.emplace(h, m);
else if (count_parameters == 3) 
    dayTime.emplace(h, m, s);

(*dayTime).something();
```